# What exactly happens when renaming tables in ClickHouse?

Tags: rename, clickhouse

I read https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/misc/#misc_operations-rename and know that all tables are renamed under global locking.

My renaming case is

```
rename table t_real_table to t_archive, t_new_data to t_real_table
```

in order to archive old `t_real_table` and make newly generated table `t_new_data` serve as `t_real_table`.

I sometimes find some queries (`select * from t_real_table`) failed (`Table t_real_table doesn't exist`) during renaming. It doesn't seem like rename is a very transient process. I wonder what exactly happens when renaming tables so that I can find a way to avoid such failures.

Is it modifying `metadata/t_real_table.sql` to `metadata/t_archive.sql` and modifying the pathname of `data/default/t_real_table/` to `data/default/t_archive/`, then modifying `metadata/t_new_data.sql` to `metadata/t_real_table.sql` and modifying the pathname of `data/default/t_new_data/` to `data/default/t_real_table/`?

If so I don't think renaming would last so long. But how to avoid failures during renaming? Does [Atomic Engine](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/7512) trustworthy？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11555#issuecomment-642011592

> Documentation is wrong. There is no global lock, it was removed in
>
> ## 6757